# LINQ Unable to retrieve related data from entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following:

`db.Products.Where(p=>p.Sectors.Where(s=>s.website_id == websiteObj.website_id)).Count();`

websiteObj is not null and has valid data. There is a many to many relationship between products and sectors. Also, there is a 1 to many relationship between sectors and websites. I don't have direct access to products from website, I have to go through the website related sectors.

Anyway, this example works:
`db.Sectors.Where(p=>p.website_id == websiteObj.website_id)).Count();`

But the issue is that the first LINQ query gives me the following errors:
`Delegate 'System.Func<BusinessObjects.Product,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments.`
`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.`

And a couple other errors.

Anyway, what am I doing wrong? This is my first attempt with LINQ.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `Any` in the inner query:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.Sectors.Any(s => s.website_id == websiteObj.website_id))
           .Count();
```

This would return all Products with at least one sector with the specified website_id.

If you want all Products where *all* sectors belong to the specified website_id, simply use `All` instead of `Any`:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.Sectors.All(s => s.website_id == websiteObj.website_id))
           .Count();
```